# Solving nonlinear bin packing optimization problem in python

Tags: optimization, constraints, bin-packing, non-linear, discrete

Is there a straight forward way (e.g. some module with a commonly used solver) to solve a problem derived from the well known bin packing problem (e.g. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) in python?

In detail, the bin packing problem where s(i) are the items' weights

```
minimize K = sum_j y_j                    # use as less bins as possible
s.t. sum_i s(i)x_i,j <= B*y_j for all j   # bin capacity B must not be exceeded
     sum_j x_i,j = 1 for all i            # all items have been fit in exactly one bin
     x_i,j, y_j being integer variables in {0,1}
```

shall be extended towards the following objective function K_nonlinear

```
minimize K_nonlinear = sum_j (y_j + Std({s(i)}) for all x_i,j =1)
s.t. # the same constraints as the bin packing problem (above)
```

Hence, not only the number of bins in use should be minimized, but also the standard deviation of the selected items sharing a bin (which will lead to some necessary compromise in general). Therefore the problem becomes nonlinear in my opinion.

I am grateful for any advice how to attack this problem using python (python api would be sufficient, algorithm itself could also be implemented in any other language).

Up to now, I have tried to extend an existing bin packing solver (based on the Coin-or branch and cut solver) about the additional part in the objective function, which failed. Presumably this is due to the induced non-linearity.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the standard deviation, it may be easier to minimize the range: `max-min`. This can be formulated in a linear fashion:

```
  Minimize xmax-xmin
  xmax >= x[i]  for all i
  xmin <= x[i]  for all i
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I am not sure though wether a solver expecting a purely linear objecitve function will be able to deal with this because max and min can be expressed in terms of absolute values (e.g. max(a,b) = 0.5*(a+b + (a-b)) ) and hence cannot be considered linear. Any ideas how to go on from there?

Comment: `minimize max(a,b)-min(a,b)` can be easily linearized as: `minimize xmax-xmin` subject to `xmax≥a, xmax≥b, xmin≤a, xmin≤b`

Comment: Now it makes sense. You introduce two additional variables ('auxiliary variables') xmax and xmin and two sets of additonal constraints as stated in your answer. Perfekt, thanks!